# Changing ng-class when clicked (nested ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, class, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

This is my angular code.. (to describe the problem I'm getting is that the nested ng-repeat for buttons repeats is behavior (when clicked) to all the "jobs" listed..

```
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="job in jobs">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group">
             <div class="btn-group" role="group" ng-repeat="status in job.statuscollection">
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{ 'btn-info': $index == selectedIndex }" ng-click="itemClicked($index)">{{status.name}}</button>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's my js code..

```
    $scope.jobs = [
    {
        _id: new Date().toISOString(),
        statuscollection: [
            { name: "Off-Site"},
            { name: "Enroute" },
            { name: "On-Site" },
        ]
        docType: "job",
    },
    {
        _id: new Date().toISOString(),
        statuscollection: [
            { name: "Off-Site"},
            { name: "Enroute" },
            { name: "On-Site" },
        ]
        docType: "job",
    }];
```

This here's my ng-click function..

```
    $scope.itemClicked = function ($index) {
         $scope.selectedIndex = $index;
         console.log($scope.jobs[$index]);
    }
```

I have more than just one job, I included only one here into the code to have less of it. but when the browser generates this data in the correct way, clicking on one of the "job's" buttons does the same thing for each job.

Meaning, if I click the button "on-site" for one job, it is duplicated for all the jobs.. how can I make it so that clicking just one of the job's buttons does it only for that job, and not all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [proper Angular approach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) to track indices across multiple `ngRepeats` is to use `ngInit` to create a local variable that aliases `$index` for each instance of `ngRepeat`. Using `$parent` to acquire its `$index` position is generally discouraged.

And in the example below, we have two `ngRepeats` and therefore two aliased index variables: `outerIndex` and `innerIndex`:

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="country in countries" ng-init="outerIndex = $index">
    <tr ng-repeat="city in country.cities" ng-init="innerIndex = $index">
      <td>{{city}}</td>
      <td>{{country.name}}</td>
      <td>({{outerIndex}}, {{innerIndex}})</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

**Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/VA1XWWrG3pghEcWli06F

---

### Final Edit

After understanding more of the context behind the question, it actually makes more sense for the OP to set an `isActive` property on the selected object instead attempting to track and match indices. That said the approach noted above is still valid and applicable for tracking indices across multiple `ngRepeats`

```
 $scope.itemClicked = function (status, job) {
   if (status.isActive) {
     status.isActive = false;
   } else {
     angular.forEach(job.statuscollection, function(status) {
       status.isActive = false;
     });
     status.isActive = true;
   }
 }
```

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/v70fY30PjoTXCrhOPVZB

Comment: given this approach, should the $scope.selectedIndex inside the itemclicked function become $scope.outerindex?

Comment: Yeah, if that's the variable you eventually want access to; I just reread your description, in which you stated you will have more `job` objects, not just one. So yes, if you want the index of the `job`, then you'll want to pass `outerIndex` to the click function.

Comment: Lux, I've tried your approach of replacing the ng-click function to pass in outerIndex now, and the second line of my itemClicked function, from this: **$scope.selectedIndex = $index;**  to this: **$scope.outerIndex = $index;**, but the class still doesn't change when clicked

Comment: The plunker I provided didn't actually have any CSS to apply, so I just updated it: http://plnkr.co/edit/v70fY30PjoTXCrhOPVZB

Comment: Let me know if exact behavior you are expecting, but in this case, we can see that the class does not apply to whichever button we click. Is this the3 expectation?

Comment: see if by adding an extra job (I've editted my js code above to have two entities for job), you'll see what I mean. the desired effect is for example, you have two Outers containing the 3 Inners. If you click on one of the Inner buttons in the first "job" the class changes on that Inner button for that first outer job (doesn't change the second job), and vice versa can be changed on the second job to any three inner buttons without changing anything on the first job.

Comment: here's a srnshot for more comprehensive explanation.. [link](http://s27.postimg.org/sm4b5hhnn/Screenshot_7.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$parent.$index` instead of `$index` to refer to the outer ng-repeated loop (the job loop, that is):

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{ 'btn-info': $parent.index == selectedIndex }" ng-click="itemClicked($parent.$index)">{{status.name}}</button>
```

`$index` is the index of the inner loop.

`$parent.$index` is the index of the outer loop.

Comment: **$parent.index** should be **$parent.$index** ? but either way, this doesn't have the desired effect.. this gives the class "btn-info to each statuscollection.name button per job. so that all three buttons inside a single job are selected, all the other jobs are left without a selected job.